# What kind of (cheap) chainrings can be used with a Deore CS-HG51 cassette

Tags: shimano, drivetrain

Will the Deore 590 be ok ?  Any other alternatives ?

Comment: Any chainring that will work with the same chain is OK.  Does not have to be the same brand or anything.

Answer (score 2):

An 8 speed drive train will work with any 8 or 9 speed crankset. Chain width is the factor that affects compatibility but there is minimal difference between an 8 and 9 speed chain.

8,9 and 10 speed systems share the same free hub width so cogs on the cassette are spaced accordingly. The chain for these sets are all different widths to fit the rear cassette. 7 and 11 speed systems have different sized hubs.

Answer (score 0):

It's an 8-speed cassette and the chainset is 9 speed, but it should work fine:
http://www.bikeradar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=15561220